# Start Process With Admin Credential and use RunAs to Execute specific exe in Program File C

Tags: powershell

I have this Code working perfectly and open CMD but it cannot run specific exe like chrome.

```
$username = "username" 
$password = "password"

$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @("soft\abbas_104",(ConvertTo-SecureString -String "Abbas1122" -AsPlainText -Force))
Start-Process -PassThru -FilePath powershell -Credential $credentials -ArgumentList '-noprofile -command &{Start-Process ',  cmd, ' -Wait -verb runas}'
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you are starting powershell within powershell to start a process? If not, `Start-Process -PassThru -FilePath 'chrome.exe' -Verb 'runas'` is sufficient

Comment: I have a one desktop application which i want to start with admin right in my other user. I have the admin credential.

Comment: with this command cmd and notepad working perfectly but i open any exe it not opening.

Comment: Guess your exe name (short name) isn't recognized with your approach. Try the full file path: `Start-Process -PassThru -Credential $credentials -FilePath 'C:\Program Files\fullPath..' -Verb 'runas'`  and don't use nested powershell executions when not required.

Comment: not working it said Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   Testabc user have the administrator right.

        //Run EXTERNAL APP AS AN ADMIN

        var pass = new SecureString();
         pass.AppendChar('t');
         pass.AppendChar('e');
         pass.AppendChar('s');
         pass.AppendChar('t');
         

        var ps1File = @"C:\Users\testabc\Desktop\LT_Admin.ps1";
        ProcessStartInfo processAdmin;
        processAdmin = new ProcessStartInfo();
        processAdmin.UseShellExecute = false;
        processAdmin.CreateNoWindow = true;
        processAdmin.WindowStyle=System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        processAdmin.Password = pass;
        processAdmin.UserName = "testabc";
        processAdmin.Domain = "soft";
        processAdmin.FileName = @"C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe";
        processAdmin.Arguments = $"-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -file \"{ps1File}\"";
        processAdmin.RedirectStandardOutput = true;           
        Process.Start(processAdmin);
```

In ps1File  I have this code

Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -Verb RunAs

Working perfectly...